# Summing Tensors

Tags: language-agnostic, math

I'm implementing the system detailed in [this paper](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~cheng/street_sig08/street_sig08.pdf).

On page 3, section 4 it shows the form that tensors take within the system:

```
R [ cos(2t), sin(2t); sin(2t), -cos(2t) ]
```

In my system, I only store R and t, since everything can be calculated from them.

However, I've got to the point where I need to sum two of these tensors (page 4, section 5.2). How can I find values for R and t after summing two tensors of this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's what you are looking for:

```
x = R_1*cos(2*t_1) + R_2*cos(2*t_2)
y = R_1*sin(2*t_1) + R_2*sin(2*t_2)

R_result = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
t_result = atan2(y,x)/2
```

Comment: Finally an answer! Unfortunately this doesn't produce correct looking results, which means either your maths is wrong or my implementation is wrong. Could you show some derivation steps so I can be confident it's my bit that's wrong?

Comment: There is not much to say: vectors given in polar representation (R, 2t) are converted into cartesian representation (x,y) because then adding is simple (just add the components). Then the result is transformed back into polar representation.

Comment: Ah I see, that is rather simple. Ok thanks, I'm sure it's my bit that's wrong now :)

Answer (score 2):

Each term reduces to

```
R_1 trg(2 t_1) + R_2 trg(2 t_2) = R_1 trg_1 + R_2 trg_2
```

where `trg` represents either sin or cos and the indexed version takes the obvious meaning. So this is a just an ordinary problem in trigonometric identities repeated a couple of times.

Let

```
Q = (R_1 + R_2)/2
S = (R_1 - R_2)/2
```

then

```
R_1 trg(2 t_1) + R_2 trg(2 t_2) = (Q+S)(trg_1 + trg_2) + (Q-S)(trg_1 - trg_2)
```

which involves [identities you can look up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

Comment: Although you're answering the question correctly, I think that is not exactly what the paper is doing. It seems it is adding up tensor fields to form a basis for each point in the space.So the angle and radius depend on what basis tensor it is referring to. Also, it seems to be some kind of exponential decay in the expressions. Not very clear, because the resultant basis is clearly not orthogonal. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: That is exactly what it's doing. Does that mean that the straight matrix summing is not the correct operation to be doing here?

Comment: @belisarius Hmmm...I've not taken the time to understand the paper, though I have now looked at it. Their results look pretty good. Since this is a recipe for procedural content generation there is some room for arbitrary decisions on the implementer's part, and *that* seems to be where the sum comes in (see equ. 4 for instance, and note that the sum is weighed): to mix different maps together or to force some parts of the map to predetermined states.

Comment: Th decision of how to combine the fields can't be completely arbitrary. for example I initially just added together R1 + R2 and t1 + t2 to get a new tensor, which produces nonsensical results.

Comment: @Martin: Clearly that won't do, but you can choose what parts of the map should be involved in the averaging and how sharply to vary the weighting. If you have two regions where the underling geometry differs, you want a smooth map between them, so you mix their contribution to the total tensor in a smooth way.

Comment: Well, I think a survey of the cited bibliography is needed to fully understand this one. Far for my time availability right now. A pity, because it seems very interesting.

Comment: I tried working through the identities on wikipedia, but the solution is evading me; I'm far too out of practice at this :( I'll have a read through any relevant looking references tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, adding two tensors is nothing more than algebra.  The two matricies have to be the same size, and you add them term by term.

You can't just add the radii and angles and plug them back into the tensor.  Do the addition properly and it'll work.  Here's the first term:

```
R1*cost(2t1) + R2*cos(2t2) = ?
```

[Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=R%2acos%28S%29+++%2B+Q%2acos%28T%29) the answer from Wolfram Alpha.  As you can see, it doesn't simplify into a nice, neat expression with an R and a T for you.

In case you haven't thought of it, put the tensor sum into Wolfram Alpha and see what it gives you.  They're better at algebra than anyone at this site.  Why not get an independent check of your work?